# Excel formula to add a cell based on the months increasing

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to show in 1 cell the value of the "same time last year".

I have 1 row of 12 columns representing each month of last year with the static value for in each month (due to space only include up to Sep 17), eg:

```
Jan-17  Feb-17  Mar-17  Apr-17  May-17  Jun-17  Jul-17  Aug-17  Sep-17
```

Eg  3   12  13  5   11  11  10  13  9

I also have 1 cell which is formulated to update as the month increases eg A1: 31/07/2018; A2: "=month(A1)" currently returning 7.

Is there a formula which will calculate Jan-17 to Jul-17 when A1 = 31/07/2018 and update to include Aug-17 when A1 = 31/08/2017?

Comment: Could you include a screenshot of your layout?  Are you trying to compare progress this year to last year?  Do you want to sum all the month values?

Comment: Use `INDIRECT` (using `month(A1)` in its argument expression) to build the address (I recommend to use R1C1 style) where the data you need is placed.

Comment: @Akina Indirect is volatile and should be avoided. Index is a much better choice.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Ian yes I'm wanting to compare progress this year against last year and I do want to sum the total of all months to the current month.  I have a screenshot but don't know how to paste it - can you please tell me how :-)

Comment: Teylyn, thanks for your example.  My result is calculating the previous months but not including the current month eg A1 is 31/07/2018, the result has calculated Jan-17 to Jun-17, how do I get Jul-17 included in the result also please?

Comment: Thank you all very much, Teylyn I've played with your formula and made it work for my sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum the cells, then you can use something along these lines:

```
=SUM(A5:INDEX(5:5,MONTH(A1)))
```

The result will update when you change the date in A1. Note that the values in row 4 are real dates, formatted to show as mmm-yyyy.

[image]